# change all links inside file_get_contents php

Tags: php, html

I'm using file_get_contents to display other websites on my website
and i want all links inside this content to be like this:

```
<a href="www.google.com/about.us"></a>
```

not like this:

```
<a href="/about.us"></a>
```

Comment: And why do you display other peoples websites? I once had someone doing that with my website and I really hated it!

Comment: What's the problem than?

Comment: i want to make online proxy

Comment: what's your problem?

Comment: my problem how to convert all links before display the content on my website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `str_replace()` on your output string. For example,

```
$newOutput = str_replace('<a href="/', '<a href="www.google.com/', $output);
```

Where `$output` is the data from your `file_get_contents()`. For example,

```
$output = file_get_contents('example.txt');
```

**EDIT:**

To match your new requirement you mentioned in the comment in order to do that only for the links in the body, then you should split the `$output` into two parts, the head and the body and then do this only on the second one. Therefore, the code you should have is:

```
$output = file_get_contents('example.txt'); //get all content
$outputArray = explode('</head>', $output); //split the content
$outputBody = $outputArray[1]; //get everything after the </head>
$newOutput = str_replace('<a href="/', '<a href="www.google.com/', $outputBody);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer
 this is work only if all  RELATIVE links
but in file_get_content there is some RELATIVE links  and some  ABSOLUTE links

Comment: As you can notice, this will not touch the absolute links, as it has to match the first string, `<a href="/`. The absolute links don't begin with a slash (/), but with `http://`, and therefore they won't be matched and replaced.

Comment: hi man i' sorry i have another qustion for you can i update this code to replace only the links inside the body not the head

Comment: Yes. I have edited my answer to match your new requirement.